# Weird file reading behavior

Tags: node.js

apparently I have a file .txt extension which only has some links like:

```
<li> <a href="http://github.com/..>
```

a .txt file saved with this line yield:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <li> <a href="ht
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

how does one read a file with such characters?

the code is:

```
const
    fs = require("fs"),
    txtFile = require("./txt.txt"),
    readStream = fs.createReadStream(txtFile);

readStream.on('readable', function () {
    console.log(readStream.read());
});
```

Comment: please show your node code. did you try to read it with `require`?

Comment: @DanielA.White added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass the file name to `require`. That's for code modules, not reading any other files.

Just pass the file name to `createReadStream`.

```
readStream = require("stream").createReadStream("./txt.txt");
```